# Updated to Ubuntu 19 and now wifi keeps disconnecting

Tags: wireless, 19.04, surface

I have a surface book 2 with Jakeday kernel which i have signed.
I updated to Ubuntu 19 the other day and now the wifi disconnects, it still says the ssid but the icon is with a "?" instead of signal strength, to make it reconnect again i need to turn wifi off and on again.

This is the output from lshv -class network:

*-network

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 00
   serial: c4:9d:ed:2d:45:9b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mwifiex_pcie ip=192.168.15.117 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:142 memory:c2500000-c25fffff memory:c2400000-c24fffff
```

I dont know if you need more logs or info?

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service` make any difference?